# Swift cropped UIImage take more than 300 MB Memory

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, uiimage

I have an Array of 96 UIImages (1280 * 720) and im cropping 720 * 720 of each UIImage and save the new image in a new Array.

After the function my Phone Memory raises up to 400 MB and dont get released.
I have try it with autoreleasepool but it doesen´t help.

Is there an problem with my cropping function or why the memory dont get released?

Here my Code:

[Image of looping through the image array and save the new cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcQgu.png)

[cropping function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpWUg.png)

[Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEvAg.png)

Comment: `UIGraphicsContext` takes 1280 * 720 * 4 = 3686400 for one image it means for one image it takes 3.68 Mb memory which will not released by `autoreleasepool`

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Use of `UIGraphicsImageBeginWithContext` and use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` like below.

For some more detail refer this From (17:00 min) : https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/416

```
        let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:720, height: 720)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size)
        let image = renderer.image { context in // Use this Image
            // Drawing Code
            Your_View.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
```